# JAVAScriptSerilized JSON String displays invalid message on fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an WEB API that is supposed to retrieve a list of events from a SQL Server database and create a response of those objects in JSON to the client

Event object:

```
public class OCEvents
{
    public long event_id { get; set; }
    public string event_date {get; set;}
    public string event_time { get; set;}
    public string event_location { get; set;}
    public string event_name { get; set; }
    public string event_image { get; set; }
    public string event_description { get; set; }
}
```

Simple Web API Controller to retrieve event JSON DATA

```
public class EventsController : ApiController
{
    private string JSONResponse = "";

    public string getEvents()
    {
        //Create class the haandles all DB related data
        DBConnect db = new DBConnect();

        //Creates List of Event Objects
        List<OCEvents> events = new List<OCEvents>();

        //get latest events posted
        db.getOCEvents(events);

        //Serialize event objects to JSON
        JSONResponse = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(events);

        //return JSON Response
        return JSONResponse;
    }
}
```

This the raw post back(response) from the event controller

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcREFOT05FXERvY3VtZW50c1xCaXpcTW9iaWxlIEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uIERldmVsb3BtZW50IERvY3VtZW50c1xQcm9qZWN0c1xPdXJDaHVyY2hBUElcT3VyQ2h1cmNoQVBJXGFwaVxldmVudHM=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2016 08:58:41 GMT
Content-Length: 1061

"[{\"event_id\":5,\"event_date\":\"13 January 2016\",\"event_time\":\"12:00\",\"event_location\":\"South Africa,North West,Rustenburg,Church\",\"event_name\":\"Imposition of Ashes\",\"event_image\":\"\",\"event_description\":\"Come anytime from 12:00 noon to 1:00 p.m for quiet meditation and prayer. Clergy will be available for the imposition of ashes.\"},{\"event_id\":7,\"event_date\":\"13 January 2016\",\"event_time\":\"19:00\",\"event_location\":\"South Africa,North West,Rustenburg,Church\",\"event_name\":\"Ash Wednesday Service\",\"event_image\":\"\",\"event_description\":\"Join us as we mark the begining of the season off Lent with a traditional Ash Wednesday service ,including imposition of ashes.\"},{\"event_id\":1,\"event_date\":\"08 January 2016\",\"event_time\":\"14:00\",\"event_location\":\"South Africa,North West,Rustenburg,Church\",\"event_name\":\"Special Worship Service\",\"event_image\":\"\",\"event_description\":\"Rev. Dr Amy Bulter, preaching Sermon--\\u0027Shine, Jesus,Shine\\u0027hebrew Scripture Lesson--Exodus 34:29-35.\"}]"
```

My issue is this error when I open the JSON tab

[Fiddler screenshot with inspector & json tab open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbdVq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The problem was that the getEvents method was returning a string instead of an HTTP Response object. So instead of returning a JSON string I used this.

```
public HttpResponseMessage getEvents()
    {
        //Create class the haandles all DB related data
        DBConnect db = new DBConnect();

        //Creates List of Event Objects
        List<OCEvents> events = new List<OCEvents>();

        //get latest events posted
        db.getOCEvents(events);

        //Serialize event objects to JSON
        JSONResponse = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(events);

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(JSONResponse)

        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        //return JSON Response
        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let the system do the JSON or XML creation depending on what the accept header is in the users original request.

```
public HttpResponseMessage getEvents()
    {
        //Create class the haandles all DB related data
        DBConnect db = new DBConnect();

        //Creates List of Event Objects
        List<OCEvents> events = new List<OCEvents>();

        //get latest events posted
        db.getOCEvents(events);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, events);
    }
```

If you want to force JSON then in your WepApiConfig remove the XML formatter.

```
    //Remove XML so only JSON is returned
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```